# how to make use of the file field in django

Tags: python, django, class, variables, django-models

what else do I need to add to that "file = models.FileField()"

this is what I have done but am still not getting any results, why that?

```
    class Course(models.Model):

        TOPIC_CHOICES = (
            ("History", "History"),
            ("Chemistry", "Chemistry"),
            ("Computer", "Computer")
        )

        lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.CharField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES, max_length=100)
        topic = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        file = models.FileField()
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.lecturer}: {self.topic}"
```

Comment: I tried to answer your question but did not know what exactly you mean by "still not getting any results". If you could specify that I may be able to help you more with your problem.

Comment: When ever I run the server and upload a file, the file doesn't get saved

Comment: Have you tried specifying the arguments I mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField), **FileField** takes two *optional* arguments.

1. `upload_to`: Sets the upload directory. The value of this argument can have several types. It can be **String**, **Path**, or a **callable** function. Here is an example:
   `upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')`
   If you want to define a function for this argument which returns the upload directory, you have to define it based on Django's specification of such function. The function should have the **instance** and **filename** arguments. Here is an example:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

2. `storage`: A storage object, or a callable which returns a storage object. This argument is used to specify a storage setting for your file-upload field. This argument enables you to choose the appropriate storage environment at runtime.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from .storages import MyLocalStorage, MyRemoteStorage


def select_storage():
    return MyLocalStorage() if settings.DEBUG else MyRemoteStorage()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(storage=select_storage)
```

Another use-case of this argument is having different storage environments for different types of files.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from .storages import LargeFilesStorage

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(storage=LargeFilesStorage())
```

As these arguments are optional, you can instantiate a **FileField** without them. The default values for these arguments are: `upload_to='', storage=None`